# Json returned shows only partial data in my Html List box from my PHP MYSQL Query

Tags: php, mysql, html, json

In my HtML List Box only a partial list of the data is shown.  I used JSON with PHP and MYSQL to populate my listbox.

I used a  "alert("Data Loaded: " + data);"  to show what JSON returns and its ok all data was successfully returned, however when I look at my list box only 52 returned data shows from the 3000. ie the list stops at "A Bronx Tale"

When I try another way by initilizing the page using   PHP only within my Html  I do get all 3000 titles. So my list box is set up to work.

Here is my Code...

// initialize page

```
        function init() {          

           $.getJSON('Reset_DVD.php',  function(data) {  
                alert("Data Loaded: " + data); 

                $.each(data, function(key, movie) {      
                   $.each(movie, function(id, title) {   
                     $('<option />').attr('value', id).text(title).appendTo('select#dvdtitle')
                   });      
               }); 

          });  
        }
```

Finally my Partial Html....

```
 <select name="dvdtitle" id= "dvdtitle"  size='10'   ></option> </select>
```

My PHP Code.... "Reset_DVD.php"

```
     <?php
       include("includes/connection.php");

       $final= array();

       $result_reset =mysql_query("SELECT * FROM dvd ORDER BY title");  

       while($rowCatagory = mysql_fetch_array($result_reset)) {

            $final[] = array($rowCatagory['title'] );
       }


       echo  json_encode($final);   

   ?>
```

Comment: 3000 items in a drop-down is a really bad design idea.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are exceeding the `get` response limit. `getJSON` sends and receives as a `GET` request.

See number 7 AJAX Methods on [14 Helpful jQuery Tricks, Notes, and Best Practices](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/14-helpful-jquery-tricks-notes-and-best-practices/)

> As an example, let's review getJSON, which allows us to fetch JSON.

```
$.getJSON('path/to/json', function(results) {
// callback
// results contains the returned data object
});
```

> Behind the scenes, this method first calls $.get. $.get then compiles the passed data, and, again, calls the "master" (of sorts) $.ajax method.

```
get: function( url, data, callback, type ) {
// shift arguments if data argument was omited
if ( jQuery.isFunction( data ) ) {
    type = type || callback;
    callback = data;
    data = null;
}

return jQuery.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url,
    data: data,
    success: callback,
    dataType: type
});
}
```

Use a `.post` post instead. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/